# Extjs superclass.constructor.call usage

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3, extjs5

I'm new to Extjs.

What is the meaning of Extjs superclass.constructor.call ?

I saw it used in Extjs examples http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/index.html

Comment: i dont understand your question. its a call of the superclass constructor. What do you mean with the usage of this call? A concrete example would be appropriate.

Comment: Thankyou very much for replying. So, we can can call parent constructor from child using this method?

Answer (score 2):

With the `this.superclass` you can access the superclass of your component.

So `this.superclass.methodName.call(this [, parameter1 [, parameter2 [...]]])` will execute the method `methodName` of your superclass and set the scope to your actual component.

If you dont know the JS function `call` i'd recommend read into [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

You now can see that `this.superclass.constructor.call(this);` will actually execute the constructor of the superclass.

Comment: That answers the OP's question but, just for interest, is there any reason why one might use this.superclass.constructor.call(this) rather than this.callParent()?

Comment: I cant think of any. Imo callParent(...) is the better way.